# Eclipse Menu (Graphical layout)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, api

My graphical layout menu has been working corectly until something (probably) happened. The project works fine, but I am not able to edit it in graphical editor. Despite the fact, that my code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:title="@string/twitter"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

It works, when I run it, but doesn't create one item in graphical layout, it does not.
This is the picture showing the graphical interface:

[image]

Clicking the add button creates this new window (which can be seen in the picture), which is, however quite useless.

I have tried changing the project build target to every possible API, but with no result.
Default program for opening xml is Android Common XML Editor (which works for everything, but not for this),

Creating new project does not seem to have any effect.

Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: If I was you, I will only use this graphical editor to have an overview of what you wrote and not to directly build elements; if you play a bit with styles, dimens and those things, your graphical editor will very soon misbehave and you'll have to test on (many) virtual or real device(s).